# Save to defaults NSMutableArray of a specific class

Tags: objective-c

I have some `NSMutableArray` of objects which are classes of mine that represent some data structure.

I am trying to save that array of objects to the user defaults, but i can see its not being saved.

I wonder, if the fact the the objects in there are instances of my own classes, and not some pointers to specific images .

```
//create an object of my class and add to the array
  Task *firstTask=[[Task alloc] initWithTag:@"A" AndColor:@"B" AndText:@"C" Done:0];
    [self.tasks addObject:firstTask]; //add to array 

//save to defaults
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:self.tasks forKey:@"tasks"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];

//retrieve (get null)
  self.tasks=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
  self.tasks=[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"tasks"]mutableCopy];
```

all the mechanism works, till i am trying to save to defaults .

How do you save these kind of data (objects of my own classes )

Comment: Is `self.tasks` null?  Or does it contain an object and that object is null?  What does `NSLog(@"%d", [self.tasks count]);` return after you retrieve?  And what does `NSLog(@"%@",self.tasks); return?

Comment: NSCoding. initWithCoder. encodeWithCoder. NSKeyedArchiver/NSKeyedUnarchiver

Comment: @JoshCaswell i get null for the log of self.tasks  .  evgeniy- what????